# Access an array stored in PSQL Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

i am pretty new in Rails and I hope you will help me.

I want to access an array and print out each element of that array. Right now with this code

```
  - @recipes.each do |recipe|
    %h2= recipe.name
    %p= recipe.description
    %p= recipe.cuisine_id
    %p= recipe.ingredients
```

recipe.ingredients print on the browser

When I try to do

```
 - recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      %p= ingredient
```

It tries to query the ingredients table, while it is just a column of the table recipe. Same result also if I use `to_s`.

Do you have any advice?

Thank you guys!

Comment: What's the output for `%p= recipe.ingredients`? Is it just a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've seen you have an `ingredients` attribute within your `recipes` model and also a model called `ingredients`, maybe you could try "aliasing" the `recipe.ingredients` column:

```
# app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  alias_attribute :new_alias, :column_name
end
```

This way you can access to that attribute with both names, the old one or the alias you setted.

```
- recipe.new_alias.each do |ingredient|
      %p= ingredient
```

And also you can select that column with an alias using ActiveRecord, like:

```
@recipes = Recipe.select('description, cuisine_id, ingredient AS some_alias')
```

And then in your view:

```
- recipe.some_alias.each do |ingredient|
      %p= ingredient
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! This was actually what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have distinct `recipe` and `ingredient` models? From your description it sounds like recipe has a `has_many` relationship with ingredients. If that is the case, then the multiple queries makes total sense.

Basically, when you try to access a model that isn't loaded already, Rails will execute a query for you. This can be troublesome if you haven't included stuff that you're accessing in your view and it can be difficult to debug. What you need to do is an `.joins(:ingredients)` in your controller where you're looking up your recipes, which will load the associated ingredients as you load your recipe. Without seeing your controller and model code I can't be much more specific though.